# how to hide/show ng-grid column externally?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am using `ng-grid`  where i want to **hide/show** columns on external *button click*.

I tried this, but its not working

```
$scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.columns[0].toggleVisible()
```

Comment: You maybe missing `$scope.$apply()` if this is being called from outside angular context.

Comment: Please provide a little more context (i.e. code).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the ng-click directive

your html button could look like this

```
<input type="button" ng-click="toggleCol(0)" />
```

and your js like this

```
var app = angular.module('myCoolGridApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.toggleCol= function(i) {
       $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.columns[i].toggleVisible()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was doing the same, but i am getting an error like  TypeError: Cannot read property 'columns' of undefined. When i try to log the $gridScope its says 'undefined'. Still i can see that when I log the entire $scope  $scope>gridOptions>$gridScope>columns

Comment: Not sure what's wrong for you, this code works for me. So also in this quick Plunker example : http://plnkr.co/edit/I9ajQw?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me also.  The issue i had was  the delay in registering the object.

Comment: Nice hack, thank you. May I add that column definition must be set to visible: false or visible: true first? That worked for me as well.