# ng-grid dynamically hide columns with no data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

Does ngGrid provide a way to programmatically hide its columns. My plan is to iterate over the data and set the visibility of certain columns (with no data) to false. Is this doable? Is there a workaround?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** So @mainguy got me part of the way and I was able to figure the rest out. For others that may come across this looking to do the same thing; here is a link to another question that also helped me. [how to hide/show ng-grid column externally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656034/how-to-hide-show-ng-grid-column-externally)

Comment: Just don't include the columns with no data in your columnDefs. Or be more specific on what your issue is.

Comment: Sorry! I should have been more specific. I have a set of 25+ predefined columns. The data fills the columns dynamically so I have no idea which column will have data until the results from the query returns. @mainguy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with this (ugly) code:

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [{
    name: "Moroni",
    age: 50,
    value: ""
  }, {
    name: "Tiancum",
    age: 43,
    value: ""
  }, {
    name: "Jacob",
    age: 27,
    value: ""
  }, {
    name: "Nephi",
    age: 29,
    value: ""
  }, {
    name: "Enos",
    age: 34,
    value: ""
  }];

  $scope.incl_names = false;
  $scope.incl_ages = false;
  $scope.incl_values = false;
  $scope.filtered = [];
  //first loop: find empty columns
  angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(row) {
    if (row.name != "") {
      $scope.incl_names = true;
    }
    if (row.age != "") {
      $scope.incl_ages = true;
    }
    if (row.value != "") {
      $scope.incl_values = true;
    }
  });
  //second loop: build new array    
  angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(row) {
    var build = [];
    if ($scope.incl_names) {
      build.name = row.name;
    }
    if ($scope.incl_ages) {
      build.age = row.age;
    }
    if ($scope.incl_values) {
      build.value = row.value;
    }

    $scope.filtered.push(build);
  });


  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'filtered'
  };
});
```

This checks in the first loop which columns are empty and sets up some booleans. Then in the second loop it creates a new array depending on the switches and then tells ng-grid to use the new array.

Of course this is not big fun with 25+ columns and you may also run into issues if you have columnDefs in your grid.

Anyhow, try it out [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xbkvsm?p=preview). Just enter a value in the last column (value) of the json.

Comment: Dude! You are effing awesome! I do have columDefs in my grid but you did point me in the right direction so I think I can develop a work around. Thanks a LOT!!!!! @mainguy

BTW, thanks for the speedy response.