# smart table column show/hide toggle

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, smart-table

I'm new to AngularJS and SmartTable...I'm currently trying to get SmartTable to have a show/hide toggle for the columns.  From what I undertstand SmartTable doesn't do this, so I am using the ng-Grid show/hide feature...trying to follow this solution:
[how to hide/show ng-grid column externally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656034/how-to-hide-show-ng-grid-column-externally)

When I implemented this solution my columns aren't showing up.

How do you set smartTable columns to "show" upon initial set up?  I think this is what I'm missing...

Here is my js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table', 'ngGrid']);

app.controller('paginationCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {
var nameList = ['Brian', 'Bob', 'Marie', 'Jennifer', 'Frank'],
    familyName = ['Smith', 'Miller', 'Patel', 'Jefferson', 'Mendez'];

...

$scope.toggleCol= function(i) {
   $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.columns[i].toggleVisible()
}

    scope.itemsByPage=15;

scope.rowCollection = [];
for (var j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
    scope.rowCollection.push(createRandomItem());
}

}]);
```

and here's my html:

```
<body ng-controller="paginationCtrl">
<p>Smart Table Example</p>
<input type="button" value="First Name" ng-click="toggleCol(0)" />
<table class="table table-striped" st-table="rowCollection">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
      <th st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
      <th st-skip-natural="true" st-sort="balance">balance</th>
      <th>email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
      <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
      <td>{{row.balance}}</td>
      <td>{{row.email}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center" colspan="5">
        <div st-displayed-pages="7" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-pagination=""></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

You can see my entire setup on my plunker example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6F8NsDdgaWranTXeIQuV?p=preview

Thanks!!

Comment: You are saying you want to use ngGrid but you are not. Without that you wont get $gridScope. Also look at your console for other errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case anyone else is trying to do this, I ended up not going to ngGrid route.  I was able to use buttons and ng-hide to accomplish what I wanted. 
For my html I did this:

```
<button ng-click="firstNameToggle = !firstNameToggle" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">First Name</button>
    <button ng-click="lastNameToggle = !lastNameToggle" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Last Name</button>
    <button ng-click="balanceToggle = !balanceToggle" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Balance</button>
    <button ng-click="emailToggle = !emailToggle" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Email</button>
  </div>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped" st-table="rowCollection">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-hide="firstNameToggle" st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
      <th ng-hide="lastNameToggle"st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
      <th ng-hide="balanceToggle"st-skip-natural="true" st-sort="balance">balance</th>
      <th ng-hide="emailToggle">email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
      <td ng-hide="firstNameToggle">{{row.firstName}}</td>
      <td ng-hide="lastNameToggle">{{row.lastName}}</td>
      <td ng-hide="balanceToggle">{{row.balance}}</td>
      <td ng-hide="emailToggle">{{row.email}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

and my js:

```
app.controller('basicsCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {
scope.rowCollection = [
    {firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com'},
    {firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'), balance: -2323.22, email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com'},
    {firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'), balance: 42343, email: 'raymondef@gmail.com'}
];
scope.getters={
    firstName: function (value) {
        //this will sort by the length of the first name string
        return value.firstName.length;
    }
}
scope.firstNameToggle = "false";
scope.lastNameToggle = "false";
scope.balanceToggle = "false";
scope.emailToggle = "false";
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but wrote this directive that solves it. 
 it do all alone.

https://github.com/cesardmoro/tableColumnToggler

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more dynamic solution i would recommend having an array of column objects like this:

```
 $scope.columns=[{name: 'firstName', template: 'template1.html'}, {name: 'lastName', template: 'template2.html' }];
```

And you render these columns in the smart table body:

```
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
      <td ng-repeat="col in columns">
        <div ng-include src="col.template"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
```

I have a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gihIyp?p=preview) example when i define the columns array and have template files for each column. This one also has Drag n' Drop funcitonality using lrDragNDrop.